# is client need its private key in mutual authentication

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

when send request to a server, if mutual authentication is needed, the server always give me a `.p12` or `.pfx` file, which contain a client certificate, a client private key.

In my understanding, the mutual authentication process only request client to send its certificate to server, and verify server's certificate do not need a client private key. So why they cannot just send me a certificate? Or is there something I miss?

Comment: You do need the private key. It's used in the SSL/TLS handshake to sign a challenge. This is the only way you can prove that you're the rightful holder of the client certificate (which itself is public).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks，it helps me a lot to understand the process